# Retain all values with multiple lists

Tags: java, list, collections, set

In java, I have `List<Integer> source, list1, list2`.
So, I have to retain `source` with `list1` and `list2` like

```java
// #source = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, #list1 = {1, 2}, #list2={3}

source.retainAll(list1, list2);

// New source should like #source = {1, 2, 3}
```

But the `retainAll` will only accept one argument but we have to pass multiple arguments.
Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Method [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) doesn't have reloaded version with two parameters. You can use API Collection's interface (method [`Collection.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-)) to merge two lists, for example:

```java
List<Integer> source = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(3);
list1.addAll(list2);

source.retainAll(list1);

System.out.println(source);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can *flatten* two lists into one *set* and then use [`retainAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)) method, or use [`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) method instead:

```java
List<Integer> source = new ArrayList<>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
List<Integer> list1 = List.of(1, 2);
List<Integer> list2 = List.of(3);
```

```java
source.retainAll(Stream.of(list1, list2)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet()));

System.out.println(source); // [1, 2, 3]
```

```java
List<Integer> target = source.stream()
        .filter(e -> list1.contains(e) || list2.contains(e))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(target); // [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

You may use var args in `retainAll()` as parameter.

You can call `retainAll()` providing any number of parameters.

Like,

```java
source.retainAll(list1, list2, list3);

private void retainAll(List<Integer>... lists){
    // you logic goes here
}
```